# Отобразить перенос строк из json ответа

Tags: jquery, json

Получаю ответ ajax'ом от сервера в формате json такого вида:
`{"success":true,"data":{"answer":"first line\r\nsecond line boom\r\n123","answer_id":433}}`

Потом раскидываю данные под местам при формировании html блока и вывожу, т.е. в нужном месте например +respose.data.answer+

Проблема в том, что текст в данном случае текст у меня сплошняком, т.е. пробелы есть, а переносы строк не отрабатывают.

Была мысль перед вставкой в html регуляркой прогнать и заменить `\n` на `<br>`, но, думаю, это явно неправильный вариант решения. Как быть?

Comment: Кроме как заменой с `\r\n` на `<br>` - никак. `\r\n` - это `text/plain`, а `<br>` - это `text/html`, если явно не указать заголовки `text/plain`, браузер вам не отобразит переносы, если конечно только зайти в `view-source:http://site.ru/` - тогда увидите переносы, ну или в `textarea` закините =)

Answer (score 1):

Можно разбить строку методом `.split()` на массив и вывести каждую в своем теги `<p>`

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script>
  const str = "first line\r\nsecond line boom\r\n123";
  const list = str.split(/\r\n/);

  const $p = $('<p class="text" />');
 
  const paragraphs = list.map(txt => {
    return $p.clone().text(txt);
  });

  $('#app').append(paragraphs);
</script>
```

Comment: Не, оборачивать в параграф точно не нужно.  Там и без того в параграф помещается. Но с другой стороны, можно попробовать сплитом br'ы расставить? Что быстрее работает str.split или str.replace (простая замена с флагом g)?

Comment: @Aaron `.split()` разбивает на массив, на выходе `["first line", "second line boom", "123"]`.